# Grouping groups in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, group-by

I have a collection of items, and every item is in some groups.
I show the collection in a WPF Listview and want to group by the groups, but that is not possible becuase i have a IEnumerable :-). And a row has to show up not only once.

Does anybody have an idea how i can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTemplate for the inner item and inside the inner data template another Listview can be used to display that group items.

Comment: But if i sort the "Main" GridView the SubViews are not sorted ?
Its difficult to compare them afterwards ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747277.aspx) and a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) to show the grouping levels in your datastructure.

I don't know exactly what your data structure looks like. If you've flattened data you possibly need to change this kind of data structure

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Group { get; set; } // A prop you want the grouping on
    public string AnotherItemProp { get; set; } 
}

public IEnumerable<Item> Items // used as your list source somewhere
```

To this:

```
public class Group
{
    public string AnotherGroupProp { get; set; } // grouping value from flattened
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string AnotherItemProp { get; set; }
}   

public IEnumerable<Group> Groups { get; set; } // Used by treeview
```

Comment: But i use a ListView and as a View a GridView in it.
Thats necassary because of the columns, sorting and so on.

A Treeview is no option for me,... :-(
Any other approach?